# touch -d alternative in MAC OS X

Tags: macos, bash

I need to change modification time of all my files in a folder 1 hour back (daylight saving issues with some software)

The thing is that
`touch -m -r {} -d '-1 hour'`

Doesn't work on MAC OS X

Any nice trick I can use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
find /startdir -type f -exec touch -m -A-010000 {} +
```

If you remove `-type f`, it will also affect directories, not just files.

See `man touch`.